# SQL Conditional SELECT from 2 tables

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

I'm new to SQL and was hoping I could get some help with the following query.

I have 3 tables:

- students(name, student_id);
- exam_results(module_code,student_id,grade);
- projects(module_code,student_id,grade).

I would like to SELECT the student name, grade and module_code, however some modules have both an exam AND a project associated with them. So if that is the case, I want to grade to be the average from projects and exams, otherwise just the grade from exams.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: @BradM I find it shorter to type http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT s.student_id, s.name, m.module_code, avg(m.grade) as grade from students s 
inner join 
(select module_code, student_id, grade from exam_results 
union all select module_code, student_id, grade from projects) as exam_module m 
on s.student_id = m.student_id
group by s.student_id, s.name, m.module_code
```